# Are Namespaces necessary everywhere in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

Im new to Laravel and namespaces, but a colleague told me i have to use the namespaces and place all my models in a folder in the app directory, named after the project.

As far as i know this means that in every single controller that uses one or more models, have have to set "use" for every model my controller needs. Example:

```
<?php
use Foo\Entities\Entity;
use Foo\Entities\Inheritance;
use Foo\Entities\Type;

class EntitiesController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {

        $inheritances   = Inheritance::all();
        $entities       = Entity::all();

        return View::make('settings/entities')
            ->with('entities', $entities)
            ->with('inheritances', $inheritances);
    }

}
```

If we asume that the associated models above will be used everywhere, would it be completely crazy to put the models in the /app/model/ folder and if a controller need a model which overwrite the standard system, then use namespaces?

Comment: They're not mandatory in Laravel, but they do help you organise your code.... and you don't need `use` but can reference each object by its namespace directly in the code, or specify a namespace at the top of the class

Comment: I believe in 4.3, they are going to be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: namespaces are NOT a Laravel thing, but a PHP feature created to better organize our code.

So, if you want your code organized, you should use namespaces for everything and, yes, you'll have to add 'use' clauses in the top of most of your PHP files. But in Laravel you also can be free to not use namespaces at all, you just have to add your autoload classes directories to your `composer.json` file:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "models"
    ],
},
```

Execute

```
composer dumpautoload
```

So Composer read all files in your models folder, to create a class map of them, and then you can just drop all uses clauses:

```
class EntitiesController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {

        $inheritances   = Inheritance::all();
        $entities       = Entity::all();

        return View::make('settings/entities')
            ->with('entities', $entities)
            ->with('inheritances', $inheritances);
    }

}
```

To not use namespaces in your PHP application, these days, may be considered a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). The only 'part' of Laravel where people doesn't usually use namespaces is Controllers, but this is also changing in Laravel 5, where controllers will be namespaced by default, but still, you will have the option to not use them, because this is a Composer/PHP thing, not Laravel.

Taylor Otwell has 3 big things always in mind when creating features and evolving Laravel: Best practices, fast coding and beautiful code.

**EDIT**

Answering your comment, if **all** your controllers needs to have access to some service or even model, why not add it to your BaseController?

But you may have to take a read at the repository pattern, because your controllers should not really be aware of your models. Developers are now creating a new layer (repository) between controllers and models, and perform the operations in those layers. You can, also, make use of Laravel Dependency Injection to help you with those `use` clauses you don't like.

It would be something like this:

Create a repository interface:

```
interface EntityRepositoryInterface {

}
```

Create the repository:

```
use Foo\Entities\Entity;

class EntityRepository {

    public function find($id)
    {
         return Entity::find($id);
    }

    public function all()
    {
         return Entity::all();
    }

}
```

Create your controllers using your repository:

```
class EntitiesController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct(EntityRepositoryInterface $entityRepository)
    {
        $this->entityRepository = $entityRepository;
    }

    public function index()
    {

        $entities = $this->entityRepository->all();

        return View::make('settings/entities')
            ->with('entities', $entities);
    }

}
```

And you have to tell Laravel Dependency Injection what to instantiate when it needs a `EntityRepositoryInterface`:

```
App::bind('EntityRepositoryInterface', 'Foo\Entities\EntityRepository');
```

Comment: Makes sense. But will it be considered bad practice to partly use namespaces if a class needs to be overruled?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your 'class overruled' question related to namespaces, but edited to talk about practices.

Comment: I would absolutely not tell people that "you may have to take a read at the repository pattern, because your controllers should not really be aware of your models."  The repositories pattern is useful for certain situations, but should not be used for no reason for all models.  Controllers can absolutely access models directly, and that isn't a code smell.  The extra complexity of using repositories should be used only when the situation makes it useful.  Many PHP devs who are new to these development patterns are blindly overusing them everywhere, making simple projects unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with putting your models anywhere you like. In fact, I put all my models  that extend directly from Eloquent in `app/models`.  You are free to follow this, or not follow it, in your own project.

However, this does come with a caveat.  Very few of my classes actually directly interact with these models ([Repositories](http://www.slashnode.com/reusable-repository-design-in-laravel/) are pretty much it).  Those I do put in separate namespaces which are then [injected](http://www.sitepoint.com/dependency-injection-laravels-ioc/) into my controllers.  Consequently, I must either `use` each repository that a controller needs at the top of each file or specify the fully qualified class name every time I reference it.